# Is it possible to set InstancePerRequest as default instance scope option for Autofac?

Tags: dependency-injection, autofac, autofac-configuration

Autofac `InstancePerDependency` as the default if no other option is specified.
Is it possible to set `InstancePerRequest` as default instance scope option for Autofac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to change the default lifetime scope preference on the container.